# Calling an instance method from a class method

Tags: ruby, class-method, instance-methods

I have this class:

```
class MyClass
@@variable = 9
    def initialize
        @@variable -= 1
    end 
    def self.tracker
        puts @@variable
        if @@variable <9
            puts "#{action}"
        end
    end

    def action
        puts "The number is less than 9!"
    end    
end
```

And when I try to call the class method:

```
MyClass.tracker
```

I keep getting this error:

```
`tracker': undefined local variable or method `action' for MyClass:Class (NameError)
```

Is it not possible to call an instance method from a class method or vice versa? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's not so much wrong as it doesn't make any sense. Instance methods apply to *instances*. Without an instance there's no context. Why not make this `self.action` as it appears to apply only to the class context?

Comment: Tip: Although you can use class variables like `@@variable`, they're generally troublesome and should be avoided. The class and its instances are supposed to have a degree of separation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you mix class and instance methods in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call an instance method you need to create an instance of the object. In ruby calling 'new' creates an instance of a class.

You can change this line

```
puts "#{action}"
```

To this:

```
puts "#{new.action}"
```

`.new` inside of the class will make a new instance of the class you are in. Which will also run your `initialize` and decrease `@@variable` by one. The way the class is written right now we never past `if @@variable <9` unless you are making instances of the class outside of the code you shared.

Overall this is a pretty odd class. It isn't common to use class variables like this. It is much more common to create an instance of a class, use instance variables/methods to house your logic.